# Angular 2 persist state of component for re-creation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, architecture, angular

Consider the following scenario: `Category` component has a list of questions, which may change by user event. It's most suitable to render each question as an individual view by iteration, as number of the questions is unknown. Thus `Question` component.

```
selector: 'category'
template: <question *ngFor="question of questions" [question]=question />
export class Category {
  questions: Question[] = questionsA;
  ... internal state ...
}

selector: 'question'
export class Question {
  @Input() question: Question;
  ... internal state ...
}
```

Now, if the questions array *questionsA* changes to *questionsB*, brand new `Question` components are instantiated which is fine. However, this is also the case when questions array changes back to original *questionsA*. But I want to retrieve those original components with their state, and not new components.

Does Angular 2 provide a mechanism to reuse the component, which was earlier instantiated with the same object by `*ngFor`, or is my only choice to persist and poll the state of component by question with an injected service?